# Linux Port 80 to redirect to a Windows box

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, iis, fedora, port

I have 2 servers here at work. One is a Windows 2008 Server R2 (for safety's sake, lets use 192.168.1.100) and the other is a Fedora 14 (192.168.1.101). Currently when you hit our subdomain, x.test.com, our routers tell it to go to our Fedora box, and since Apache is installed and listening to port 80, it displays the Fedora Apache Test Page. It's obvious that I don't use port 80 for this machine, however I do use NAGIOS on it and its always nice to be able to access that from anywhere in the world. So when I want to access it, I just type x.test.com/nagios. Now here comes the dilemma....

On the Windows R2 box, we recently have installed a program that requires us to setup a web server using IIS7. Because of this application, I'm going to be creating a new subdomain called y.test.com, but since we only have 1 WAN/router, it will still get pointed to our Fedora box. That being said, it wants to use port 80 as well (or whatever port I damn well wish to assign it).

So my question is: since our router is pointing to the Fedora 14 box (.101), and I want to make sure I can access NAGIOS from anywhere in the world, how do I tell Apache (httpd) to redirect port 80 to the other server (.100)? If not possible, what are my other options?

I have rinetd installed on Fedora and have even tried the option 192.168.1.101 80 192.168.1.100 80 and it didn't seem to work "because port 80 was already bound"

Thoughts? and Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this with an Apache 2.2 proxy setup.  Add something like this to httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass           /newapp http://y.test.com
ProxyPassReverse    /newapp http://y.test.com
```

Make sure mod_proxy is installed and enable then restart apache.  Now you should be able to access the app as http://x.test.com/newapp

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a different port for one of those sites if you only have a single public IP address. 8080 is a standard alternate http port, so have one server listen on 8080 and the other on 80. Then update your forwarding on the router.